# How do I get my Media Player to double buffer?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

My media player is in a service object of it's own. Here's the create code.

```
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(path);
        player.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } 
    player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
}
```

It is streaming from online. However, it's pretty choppy 3 minutes later. I want to double buffer this to help remove that. Any ideas on how I should do this?

Comment: Why do you think double buffer would help? Try and see if it happens by playing an offline video.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the android [Double Buffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html) class?

Comment: A (native) buffer of doubles?